# Typeahead field, that has a footer with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

So let's say I have a simple input text field, with autocomplete support from twitter's typeahead library, that fetches information remotely, like that:

```
$(".typeahead")
 .typeahead({
   name: "boats",
   valueKey: 'name',
   remote: {
     url: baseSearchURL+"/_search?q=%QUERY"
   },
   footer: "<a url=/search?q=%QUERY>View all the results</a>",
   template: "{{name}}",
   engine: Hogan })
```

What I am looking for, is a way to pass the user's input to the HTML in the footer section , so I can create a link to a page with all the available results.

Obviously, the above code section for the `footer` field, doesn't work as intended, but that's what I am trying to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing an HTML string to `footer` you can pass a DOM element. Create a DOM element that contains your `<a href...>`, and using Typeahead events just update it.

Comment: I tried initially to supply a DOM element with jquery, but that didn't work. I presume, due to a syntactic error, because I tried again now and it worked fine. Still my problem remains, since the Typeahead events don't cover all the edge cases. Most events, will get fired only once (`initialized`,`opened`,`closed`) and some won't be fired at all (`selected`,`auto completed`) since the user won't find what he is looking for and follow the link, to look at a bigger list. Any ideas on how to get the complete input of the user?

Comment: I think you need `typeahead:opened`.